# Save graph structure in breadboard using Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I´m using breadboard (http://breadboard.yale.edu/) to create an experiment where players are nodes in a network and can make decisions. Breadboard also automatically creates a datafile where certain events are saved. For example, to create a player choice and save the output to the datafile, I use:

```
// add player action to get Consent
a.add(v,       
 [name: "Proceed",
  result: {v.private.consent = 1},
 event: [name: "Consent",data: [player: v.id,consent: 1]]]
)
```

To record global variables, I use:

```
// recording initial parameters into the dataset
a.addEvent("InitParameters", 
["nPlayers" : nPlayers,
 "EdgeProb" : EdgeProb,
 "nRounds" : nRounds,
])
```

However, I also need to record the structure of the network into my data somehow. In the script window, I can print the structure of the network using:

```
 g.E
```

However, I can´t seem to record this as an Event to the dataset. If I run the experiment and include

```
 a.addEvent("Structure",
 ["Structure": g.E])
```

The experiment simply stops at this line.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just a note - this really isn't a Gremlin syntax/usage issue. It's more related to breadboard's internal Domain Specific Language wrapping Gremlin. You might have better luck getting this question answered directly from the developers of breadbox.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @stephenmallette! I also posted on the Breadboard Github page and in their Gitter Feed but I didn´t get an answer so far...